# Download a zip file from s3bucket, extract it and save the required file in to local file path .. using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to download a Zip file from S3 bucket (not from cli) using a function. What I have learnt  is to have a function with remote and local params so I have created this function:

```
public function downloadFile($remoteFile, $bucket, $localFilePath) {  
        $this->client->getObject(array(  
            'Bucket' => $bucket,  
            'Key' => $remoteFile,  
            'SaveAs' => $localFilePath  
        ));
    }
```

And called this function in my script.

Given a remote file, I need to extract zip and save a particular file in to local file path.

How can I achieve this?

```
$s3 = Storage\S3::getInstance();  
$s3->downloadFile($remoteFile,$localFile,S3_BUCKET);
```

I have created this function but I am not sure on how a particular zip has to be fetched and to extract a seperate file. I am new to using S3 with php.

Comment: you could achieve this task using native Zip function from PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php